# Why is viewWillAppear: on my contained view controller being called twice from transitionFromViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a `MainViewController` managing a container view. In `MainViewController`'s `viewWillAppear:` method, I check if the user is a member or a guest, and then call `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:` to swap the `MemberViewController` or `GuestViewController` into the container view as appropriate.

The problem is, `viewWillAppear:` on my `MemberViewController` is being called **twice** from within `transitionFromViewController...`. This is a problem as I'm making network calls there which I don't want to duplicate.

Why, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but moving the code that calls `transitionFromViewController...` from `MainViewController`'s `viewWillAppear:` to its `viewDidAppear:` fixed the problem.

([If you can clarify any of this for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865601/in-which-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle-method-should-various-tasks-be-performed), it would be most helpful.)